# How can I stop third party applications from accessing server side data through requests?

Tags: php, security, client-server

I'm making an online user account system for a game being created in Unity3d. The Unity application sends WWW requests to php files, and as a result some action is performed and the application gets feedback.

However, I've noticed that this method allows any application to send these requests. Can this be avoided? Is my method of communication between the client and the server flawed?

How can I make it so that only my application can send these requests?

Answer (score 0):

Look up session key (or sesskey).

Basically it's a random string generated on the server and is valid as long as the session is active. This session key is sent to the client side and is one of the values in any server call. Each time the server compares the string to the one it has.

whenever the user logs out the session key is destroyed and a call from any third party application using the last sesskey will be denied.

Comment: That makes sense, but what's stopping a client from reading this key and using that on their third party application while their session is still valid?

Comment: There's no simple answer for this and it depends on the way your code is written. One of the rules I myself work by is "Never trust the client", this means every important request is checked for permissions and other limitations on the server. This will make your code a little bit more complex but more secured.